# What do the "grass puffs" mean on Pokemon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

When travelling, I sometimes see little "puffs" of leaves and grass appear on the map. Are these a sign of Pokémon, or just a bit of visual flavour?

Comment: There we go, thanks @Jouramie, just couldn't find the question via search.

Answer (score 1):

It means that chances of finding wild pokemon there is higher but no where near guaranteed.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4s0x38/whats_the_point_of_moving_grassleaves_on_the_map/)

Also from personal experience